# A classic riddle with a soft touch

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Bane of sailors.
>
> Bliss for the head.
>
> I am complete when I am dead.

**What am I?**

This one perplexed a game group, including a sailor, so I hope to see you fare better.

Some hints:

> First line is literal. Second line more or less literal: a pleasant state of being for the human head. Third line is wordplay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> A calm?

Bane of sailors.

> When there’s no wind, the ship can’t move.

Bliss for the head.

> Wonderful silence, or a calm state of mind.

I am complete when I am dead.

> The calm is complete when there’s absolutely no wind, i.e. when it‘s »dead«.

Comment: That's it! Nice work. Thank you for playing! I'll make more.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Fruit?

Bane of sailors.

> If sailors can't get enough fruit they get scurvy (a disease you get without proper vitamins).

Bliss for the head.

> Fruit has lots of fiber which would make it easy to use the "head" or toilet on a ship.

I am complete when I am dead.

> Fruit's purpose is complete when it is dead because that's when it's seeds can start to grow.

Comment: This isn't what I had in mind, but I love this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> sponge

Bane of sailors.

> There are found in the ocean.

Bliss for the head.

> Soft?

I am complete when I am dead.

> Then you can use them in your kitchen.

Comment: Yeah, they're found in the ocean, but how exactly does that make them the bane of sailors?

Answer (score 2):

You might be...

> <s>A wave</s> Air?

Bane of sailors.

> As in, wind

Bliss for the head.

> As in, getting some air.

I am complete when I am dead.

> <s>Like a wave at a concert/stadium</s> There is dead air when the radio/show is over

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out there...

> a swab?

Bane of sailors.

> Swabbing the deck is not the most uplifting of endeavours.

Bliss for the head.

> Cotton swabs have many uses in the maintenance of a person's head.

I am complete when I am dead.

> You can never get a ship's deck actually cleaned up. As soon as you think you're done, someone walks in with their dirty boots and you have to start again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Fog

Bane of sailors.

> Sailors can't see where they are going

Bliss for the head.

> My head is foggy

I am complete when I am dead.

> Dead fog doesn't move int the wind en is much denser.